# Angular - Waiting for backend call to finish and not skip

Tags: angular, subscription

New to angular and I have this issue I have been trying to solve.
I have looked all around for a solution but with no luck for my situation.

so here is my problem.

**I have a call to back end.**

```
private setDocId(document: Document){
    this.api.getInfo(randomNumber: number).subscribe(data => {
    if (data === 1) {
      document.id = data;
       }
    })
}
```

**regular validation check**

```
   private checkIfDocExists(document: Document){
    return document.isExists ? document.approved = true : document.approved = false:
}
```

**validation both methods**

```
private isValid(): boolean {
   this.setDocId(document);
   const isExists = this.checkIfDo1cExists(document);
   return isExists && document.id !== null;
}
```

as you can see last method returns validation if both conditions are true;
both condition are true, however since the backend call does not wait and continues it returns false since it has not completed initialization yet.

is there a way to let first method (with api call to back end) to wait to finish before it continues?
without using setInterval or setTimeout?

thanks.

Comment: Can you show how the validation is being used now?

Comment: is document a global variable?

Comment: @AndrewAllen yes its global and passed as a param

Comment: @Tommi this is exactly how I use it only with different names. I am only trying to make my method wait for results before going on to return value. thanks

Comment: Okey strange, because the code in your question is only showing you declaring the validation not how they are being called /used. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `async` and `await` to let the first method complete first.

```
private async setDocId(document: Document){
    const data = await this.api.getInfo(randomNumber: number).toPromise();
    if (data === 1) {
      document.id = data;
    }
}

private isValid(): boolean {
   await this.setDocId(document);
   ...
}
```

I think you could get this to work by using a BehaviorSubject and performing the check inside `setDocId`.

```
private isValidSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
isValid$ = this.isValidSubject

private setDocId(document: Document): void {
    this.api.getInfo(randomNumber)
    .pipe(
        map(data => {
            if (data === 1) {
                document.id = data;
                const isExists = this.checkIfDo1cExists(document);
                this.isValidSubject.next(isExists && document.id !== null);
            }
        }),
    ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Just a gentle reminder that toPromise is being deprecated in RxJS 7 and will be removed in RxJS 8

Comment: exactly. its a good answer however, I work only with observables. is there a way to do this without a promise?

Comment: I updated my answer to use observables

Comment: Adding on to my comment that you can still convert observables to promise with firstValueFrom() / lastValueFrom() instead of toPromise() . More on this [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated)

Comment: hi. I have tried your recent answer, however, after it gets to Map it jumpts directly to return isValid and after it returns insValid only then it continues. which results in a false value. thanks